Check Box selection and Powershell
I am playing around with WPF powershell stuff... I have a simple window which searches a user then displays all their information in textboxes. One specific box for each bit of info. Name, displayname, email etc.
I want to be able to edit the user, so used textboxes as they are editable. I have placed a tick box by each box. What i want to do is if you edit the entry and tick the tick box it will edit that entry for the user.. So you could edit three entries and tick three boxes when you hit the edit button it changes that entry. This would also be dependant on the domain you selected.
Example of what i mean

What is the best way to code this? So i coded the search user with if end elseif and that is fine does what it needs to do.
if ($DomainSelect -eq "Domain1") {

Code here 

}
elseif ($DomainSelect -eq "Domain2") {

Code here

}

So i was thinking in those blocks... Could you use -and statements in there? or would that get too messy or confusing for it with the chance not all are selected and then multiple domains and selecting multiple tick boxes at times?
Or is there a better way? Not really played around further, was hoping to get some more insight and go from there.
Thanks

The best way to code what? You haven't described what you want to do differently based on the domain selection...

@MathiasR.Jessen What i want to do is if you edit the entry and tick the tick box it will edit that entry for the user.. So you could edit three entries and tick three boxes when you hit the edit button it changes that entry. This would also be dependant on the domain you selected.

Right but what dependency exists on the domain selection? Should you only be able to edit display names in some domains?

@MathiasR.Jessen You can edit every field. The domain is selected so it applies the changes to the selected domain. Which is going to be the one your selected when you searched the user. Then you can edit the field/s then tick the box of the editted field thne apply changes. Thanks

It sounds like the two sets of conditions (whether a checkbox is ticked vs whether a given domain was selected) are entirely unrelated.
In other words, you can decide on the data that you need to pass to your backend system (eg. Active Directory) separately from the decision about which server to contact:
# prepare splatting table
$userUpdateData = @{
  Identity = $currentUsername
}

# populate entry values associated with checked checkboxes
if ($firstNameCheckbox.Checked) {
  $userUpdateData['GivenName'] = $firstNameTextBox.Text
}
if ($lastNameCheckbox.Checked) {
  $userUpdateData['SurName'] = $lastNameTextBox.Text
}
if ($displayNameCheckbox.Checked) {
  $userUpdateData['DisplayName'] = $displayNameTextBox.Text
}

# decide on target server based on selected domain
if ($DomainSelect -eq "Domain1") {
  $userUpdateData['Server'] = 'dc01.domain1.tld'
}
elseif ($DomainSelect -eq "Domain2") {
  $userUpdateData['Server'] = 'anotherDC.domain2.tld'
}
else {
  throw 'unexpected domain selection, cannot map to domain controller'
}

if ($userUpdateData.Count -gt 1) {
  # at least 1 updated property was checked, let's update the backend
  Set-ADUser @userUpdateData
}

Dynmically building a dictionary of parameter arguments and passing it with the @ operator is known as splatting, and is perfect for this particular kind of invocation where the target parameters might vary.

@MathiasR.Jensen, that makes sense. Seems a good way of doing it, especially with the amount of data that can be changed.
So i played about with your basis, i presume i need something else but when i click the button to enact the changes it does nothing.
The code is wrapped in a function. I presume its not pulling the 'Set-ADUser' command in the final if statement
